# Execution time goes up the more threads I use OpenMP, what's wrong?

Tags: c++, concurrency, parallel-processing, openmp

I have written a program that takes in a dictionary and finds all the words in the dictionary that are palindromes. I have attempted to parallelize the going through of this dictionary, and the execution of the logic that checks whether a word is a palindrome using OpenMP. However, when I've noticed that execution time goes up as I allow the program to utilize more and more threads. What could be the explanation for this? Is there a bug in my code?

```
#pragma omp parallel    //block of code that we want to execute using multiple threads
#pragma omp single  //we only want one thread to iterate through the foor loop and spawn tasks for the other threads
{
    #pragma omp task untied     /* iterating through the for loop is the main task, so 
                     * burden should be shared if execution is suspended
                     */
    {
        for (set<string>::iterator i = wordList.begin(); i != wordList.end(); ++i){
        #pragma omp task    //spawn the tasks of evaluating whether each word should be inserted into palindrome list
            {
                if (isPalindrome(*i)){  //if the word is by itself a palindrome, insert
                    palindromes.insert(*i);
                }
                /* if the reverse of the current word is in the wordlist and it hasn't already been inserted,
                 * insert them both into set of palindromes
                 */ 
                else if (wordList.find(reverseWord(*i)) != wordList.end()){
                    if(palindromes.find(*i) == palindromes.end()){
                        palindromes.insert(*i);
                        palindromes.insert(reverseWord(*i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use a call to omp_set_num_threads(Argv[1]) to change the runtime maximum allowed threads. I am executing this program on a supercomputer, so I don't think it's a problem of my computer being "overloaded" or something. What gives? Have I misinterpreted how to use OpenMP? I am using two calls to omp_get_wtime() right before and after this code block to measure execution time.

EDIT: both palindromes and wordList are std::set, isPalindrome checks if the word is a palindrome through pointer manipulation, reverseWord returns the word reversed character for character (for this task a palindrome is also a word whos reverse is found in the wordlist, eg. saw - was.

Comment: The concurrent use and modification of `palindromes` makes this very non-parallelizable (if that is a word).

Comment: How so? Each thread is evaluating whether or not to insert a unique element into palindromes. The majority of words are not inserted, and even the ones that are, concurrent insertions into a set shouldn't be an inherent issue on parallelization imo.

Comment: What is `palindromes`? If `std::set`, then, you cannot insert into it in parallel without synchronization. Containers from the Standard library are _not thread-safe_.

Comment: [Edit] the question to include missing details, at least the missing variable declarations (`palindromes`, `wordlist`), the definition of `isPalindrome`.  We need a [mre] to have a chance to give a good answer (and not a guess).

Comment: Still not a [mre].  We need to see the function definitions, not descriptions.  If those functions do any sort of memory allocation - including passing string parameters by value - that will have very serious impacts on parallelization.

Comment: they both accept a string passed by value, and isPalindrome does pointer manipulations to compare characters symmetrically from beginning/end, reverseWord iterates through passed string in reverse order, and appends to a new string that is then returned.

Answer (score 1):

Does the amount of computation (CPU cycles) that each task executes makes up for the work done for spawning them?

I might suggest using `#pragma omp parallel for` over the tasks in here, since your word set has a fixed size during the entire operation. The problem however lies in the critical sessions when inserting the word to the `palindromes` list.

Comment: I would, but I cannot use #pragma omp parallel for for a for each loop. I would have to iterate through the wordlist once and copy the pointers of the iterator into an array and then iterate over the array. I think this is slower as i am iterating once through the entire thing extra in that case. I don't think inserting into palindromes concurrently is an issue as Im not inserting the same word ever, and the answer printed out is alright.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description of the (currently) missing code, the problem is that you repeatedly create new `string` objects to pass to `isPalindrome` and elsewhere.  Every string copy will result in a memory allocation (and subsequent free), and the standard memory allocator is not reentrant and will block one thread if another is currently allocating.

One partial solution is to pass the parameter to `isPalindrome` as a `const std::string &`, which will avoid the copy.  `reverseWord` will be a bit more problematic in this respect, since it needs to return a modified string, but the parameter could still be passed by reference.